# Wide page layout option for 1080p and 1080i screens

Tags: feature-request, design

Wondering whether SO/SU/SF/Meta could have an option for a 'wide page layout', for those of us with 1080p/1080i resolutions. The unused whitespace on both sides of the middle 'column' could be put to better use.

Comment: Do you really use your browser maximized?  How do you do any real work?

Comment: How can you stand __not__ having your browser maximized?

Comment: I hook up my laptop to a monitor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widescreen is another way for you to conceivably walk into the Large Print aisle of the local library.

Crank up the zoom on your browser and you'll see in no time that the white space will be gone. Not only that, the size of the letters will allow for you to cruise in a sling back chair while browsing through SOFU and not strain your eyes.

Another way to make use of the widescreen monitor and getting rid of the whitespace is to rotate your monitor 90° and view all your trilogy time in portrait mode.

Comment: Zooming in is indeed a fine idea, I shall use it often.

Comment: It's all about the zooma-zoom-zoom as you code a boom in your romba-room of doom.

Answer (score 6):

Alternately, you could consider this an opportunity to have 4 browser windows open.. one for [each site in the Trilogy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/)!

Comment: I tried this once using my three monitor layout at work. I woke up 4 hours later in a puddle of my own drool.

Comment: ... but 794 rep richer, so it was undoubtedly worth it.  Next time wear a bib for the drool.  I recommend http://images1.cafepress.com/nocache/product/12726171v2147483647_350x350_Front_Color-White.jpg - Who's *your* geek daddy, TheTXI?

Comment: care to revise this statement now that we have Stack Apps, SO Careers, SEDE, Nothing to Install and a dozen beta sites?

Comment: It's 2013, why is the site still 960px wide? We're developers we have 1920x or even larger monitors.